# Random number to values columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, classification

I have a large dataset with the columns 'group' and 'postcode'. An example of the df is given below:

```
Age
65+
16-25
16-25
26-39
40-64
65+
26-39
40-64
16-25
65+
```

I am trying to affect to each row value a random value with the code below

```
df['AGE'] = df['AGE'].replace({'65+': randint(65,100), '16-25': randint(16,25),
                               '26-39': randint(26,39), '40-64': randint(40,64)})
```

But what I'm getting are four random values to each of these values: `{'65+', '16-25', '26-39', '40-64'}` like so:

```
Age
73
23
23
34
42
73
34
42
23
73
```

Can someone please help me figure out what am I doing wrong by correcting my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're generating the random numbers once and just replacing your column values.

If you want a different random number for each row, you need to call `randint` for each row. Try:

```
>>> df['AGE'].apply(lambda x: randint(int(x[:2]), 100 if x[-1]=="+" else int(x[-2:])))
0    82
1    23
2    18
3    27
4    45
5    83
6    38
7    64
8    17
9    93
Name: AGE, dtype: int64
```